# replace characters in a big log file

Tags: regex, text, replace, large-files

How can I change very large log files under Windows from this:

```
   3334-444-(4)  anything   anything2
   4444-444-(4)  anything   anything2
   4744-454-(4)  anything   anything2
   48444 44-(4)  anything   anything2
   8444-444-(4)  anything   anything2
   4464-(444)-2  anything   anything2
```

to this:

```
33344444         anything   anything2
44444444         anything   anything2
47444544         anything   anything2
48444444         anything   anything2
84444444         anything   anything2
44644442         anything   anything2
```

Remove everything to position 18 in each line except digits and keep the position of a second column?

**\\Edit:** The problem is that from position 1 to 17 could be also space between digits. This is the logic that I suppose might work:
1. From pos. 1 to 17 replace '(', ')', '-' to ' ' [space]
2. From pos. 1 to 17 replace ' ' [space] to '' [nothing] and count changes
3. From pos. 1 to 17 add space after digits in accordance with each change from previous step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you can use the power of commandline-tools

```
$ sed 's/[-)(]//g' input
33344444  anything   anything2
44444444  anything   anything2
47444544  anything   anything2
48444444  anything   anything2
84444444  anything   anything2
44644442  anything   anything2
```

**update**

Sometimes it is easier to divide a complex task into smaller parts.

Assume the input looks like this (adding a ruler)

```
         1         2         3         4         5
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
   3334-444-(4)  anything   anything2
   4444-444-(4)  anything   anything2
   4744-454-(4)  anything   anything2
   48444 44-(4)  anything   anything2
   8444-444-(4)  anything   anything2
   4464-(444)-2  anything   anything2
```

**Step 1** is to use `cut` to well, cut out the first 17 characters, remove the unwanted ones and store in tmp-file.

**Step 2** is to cut characters 18 to end-of-line and store in tmp-file.

**Step 3** is to combine the tmp-files into one file.

Something like this:

```
$ cut -c1-17 input | sed 's/[-)( ]*//g' > c1

$ cut -c18- input > c2

$ paste c1 c2
```

If this doesn't approve to your aesthetic senses, you can do everything in one go using `awk`. Put the following lines in a file called "col.awk" or choose a better namne if you fell like it:

```
{
  x = substr($0, 0, 17)
  y = substr($0, 18, length($0))
  gsub(/[-)( ]*/, "", x)
}
{ printf "%-18s%s\n", x, y }
```

then call it like this:

```
$ awk -f col.awk input
```

output (again with ruler):

```
         1         2         3         4         5
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
33344444         anything   anything2
44444444         anything   anything2
47444544         anything   anything2
48444444         anything   anything2
84444444         anything   anything2
44644442         anything   anything2
```

Note that cygwin likes everything to have unix-style line endings so you might need to convert your input from windows-style to unix-style. One tool that might help you here is `dos2unix` or `fromdos` (google is your friend here).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I preserve the position of a second column?

Comment: The problem with this regular expression is that it will replace everything even on the second or third columns. You would need to restrict it from start to first space character.

Comment: @user2274366 - please see my update. Hopefully that will help you; if not, leave a comment and I'll update

Comment: This looks perfect :) I have downloaded [gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).
Could you explain me whis regex pattern: `/[-)( ]*/`
and this: `%-18s%s`

Comment: How can I also remove any zeroes from the beginning `08444-444-(4)  anything   anything2` to `84444444         anything   anything2`

Comment: `/[-)( ]*/` is just a character-class containing 4 characters (the ones you like to remove) and a qualifier, in this case a `*` meaning 0-or-many; using that together with gsub (global substitution) you get the desired effect. To remove leading zeros use `gsub(/^0*/, "")` where `^` is an anchor meaning start-of-line` followed by any any number of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Ultra Edit. It's an editor that allows you to select in column mode so you might be able to select the first 18 characters and do a replace that way.

The only other thing that comes to mind is use an editor that has a macro feature to do it.

Or write a quick and dirty program.

Answer (score 0):

Use below regular expression and replace with "" (empty string)

```
[-\(\)]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.2.html). Open the document and press CTRL+h for search and replace.

Use this regular expression in the "find what" box:

```
^([0-9]+)\-?\(?([0-9]+)\)?\-?\(?([0-9]+)\)?
```

and this in the "replace with" box:

```
\1\2\3
```

Select "Regular Expression" in search mode and then replace all.

Answer (score 0):

Really, not sure, that `Windows` can do this simple.

But..

You can install `Perl` - good language for text and strings manipulations.

Or find linux machine.

Here you can find installer: [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/)

After installation, just run this in your console (`cmd.exe`)

> perl -i.bak -ne 's/^\s// && s/[-()]//g && s/\s/\t/; print;' input.txt

This will save your backup file (`input.txt.bak`) and you get your changes in `input.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([0-9]*)([( ]|-\(?|\)-?)([0-9]+)\)?/\1\3/;ta;s/[ \t]+/         /;' file
```